# how to retrieve data from Firebase on card and fetch data to detail screen?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-app-engine

[here is card list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTlYi.png)

[in pic two I want to show data of that card I tap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY6Ob.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can retrieve data like this

you can create a model for the response you are getting

**Get Data**

Define the path from where you want to get data

**eg.**

```
FirebaseFirestore fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
```

**This will return data in stream.**

```
 fireStore.collection("TABLE_NAME").snapshots().map((event) => event.docs.map((e) => ExampleModel.fromJson(e.data())).toList());
```

so your function will look something like this.

```
Stream<List<ExampleModel>> getExampleData() {
return fireStore.collection("TABLE_NAME").snapshots().map((event) => event.docs.map((e) => ExampleModel.fromJson(e.data())).toList());
```

}